# html won't load uikit css two folders deep

Tags: html, css, uikit, subdirectory

I'm currently learning to use yootheme's uikit. I'm currently running it off of Apache 2.4.16 on my Mac, but the index.html page won't bring up the main uikit.css (or any css) buried two or more folder levels deep (as all the css files within uikit's directory are).

Here is my folder structure:

- MainSiteFolder

  - index.html
  - uikit/

    - css/

      - uikit.css
    - fonts/
    - js/

And here is the line I included in the head of index.html (copied and pasted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="uikit/css/uikit.css" />
```

If I pull out that css file and put it in any other folder I create (or the root directory), I can change the reference to "otherFolder/uikit.css" and it works perfectly... but I'd like to be able to keep things organized within multiple folders until I nail down which of the many uikit css files I plan to use.

Is there something I've missed that removes my ability to load css files that are more than one folder lever deep? Or do I need to just put everything into one css folder, despite the loss of convenience organization would bring?

EDIT: Must have been something strange with my browser (or Apache?) not realizing there were files in the folder. I don't know the reason, but removing the entire folder, and recreating it inside the directory, then uploading the files individually got it working. Though it still baffles me why it didn't work in the first place. Some sort of missing reference or something perhaps.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console to see if there are any conflicts being thrown up?

Comment: No. How would one go about doing that?

Comment: If you open index.html in your browser. In most modern browsers you can right click on the page and choose inspect (or press F12) this will launch the developer tool from there you can select console which is where you will see any errors being produced.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Unfortunately, no errors came up, though. I'll have to keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
../
```

To go to a higher directory, like:

```
href="../uikit/css/uikit.css"
```

To go 'up' one level of directories.  **../../**  goes up 2 levels, and so on ...

Alternatively , start at the root directory, in Windows it is    **C:** not sure what it would be on your system, but something followed by a   **:**

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that method. It didn't fix it though. Even giving the explicit path starting at the root directory didn't work. Which is odd, to say the least. Something weird must be up.

Comment: you could try prefixing the path with a forward slash. /uikit/css/uikit.css

Comment: Tried that as well, but to no avail. Removing and recreating/repopulating the uikit folder got it to work though. So all is well. Now I just wish I knew why it hadn't worked in the first place.